# MySQL query of available values

Tags: mysql

I have the table test:

```
cod double  PRI     
nom varchar(100)
tip varchar(50) 
des varchar(500)
pre double
```

The table contains a numeric primary key called "cod". The cod values go from 1000 to 40000.

The rows can be deleted. F/E:

Having cod:

```
1001 X X X 1.0
1002 Y Y Y 2.0
1003 Z Z Z 3.0
1004 A A A 4.0
1005 B B B 5.0
```

and if 1002 is deleted, there's a missing number between 1001 and 1003.

```
1001 X X X 1.0
1003 Z Z Z 3.0
1004 A A A 4.0
1005 B B B 5.0
```

Can I do a query to get all these missing numbers so I can suggest the user what cod values are free to register new rows?

Comment: Is there a specific (and good) reason for the value being limited to 40000? What happens if there are no available numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach.  If you have a table that is limited to 39000 rows, then create that table with all the rows to begin with.

Then, have an `IsAvailable` flag.  Instead of deleting records, you can just update the flag:

```
update test t
    set IsAvailable = 1
    where cod = < whatever >;
```

When you want to use a value, then set the available flag to 1.

Then, you can get the first 10 available slots using something like:

```
select cod
from test
where IsAvailable = 1
limit 10;
```

By the way, you refer to `cod` as an integer throughout the question, yet it is declared as a double.  I strongly suggest you make the column an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECt test1.cod - 1 AS missing_cod
FROM test AS test1
LEFT JOIN test test2 ON test2.cod = test1.cod - 1
WHERE test2.cod IS NULL
```

this should work (i think), i don't know what is going to happen if you got more than one missing number at time

Why are you using double with integer value on `cod` column?

Comment: Yeah, this won't work if there are consecutive missing numbers.